# cannot create table with foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I know this question is posted a lot, and I've checked my code carefully but couldn't find the reason why when I create the table with Foreign Key, mysql gives me an error.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Act_Model(
    -> code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    -> model VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (code))ENGINE = INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
mysql> CREATE TABLE IBT_ActItem(
    -> model VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    -> flagbit BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> PRIMARY KEY(model),
    -> FOREIGN KEY( model) REFERENCES Act_Model(model))ENGINE = INNODB;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.ibt_actitem' (errno: 150)
mysql> CREATE TABLE IBT_ActItem(
    -> model VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    -> flagbit BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> PRIMARY KEY(model))ENGINE = INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
```

when I used `show engins;`, for InnoDB it gave me:

```
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
```

Can you help me to find where is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: Try to create the table first, then add the foreign key.

Comment: you should make the pk before setting fk to it.

Comment: Are you sure you want it that way round? Looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: @ Adem: I followed your advice to `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, then drop the tables, and then create the tables again. Still the same error.

Comment: @ njk: `ALTER TABLE IBT_ActItem ADD CONSTRAINT IBT_ActItem FOREIGN KEY (model) REFERENCES Act_Model (model);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.#sql-c3_ae08' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a unique index on the model column in the parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE Act_Model(
 code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
 model VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (code),
 UNIQUE KEY model (model)
 )ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: NOTE: this will enforce a "one -to- zero-or-one" relationship between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL requires that you have a UNIQUE KEY or PRIMARY KEY constraint on the column(s) that is the target of the FOREIGN KEY constraint.

To add a unique key, you can use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE Act_Model ADD CONSTRAINT Act_Model_UX UNIQUE KEY (model) ;
```

---

You already have the `model` column defined as the PRIMARY KEY in the `IBT_ActItem` table.

If you add a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint and a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the `model` column of the other table (`Act_Model`), you are in effect specifying a "one-to-one(optional)" relationship between these two tables.

The UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) KEY goes on the parent table, which is the "one" side of the "one-to-many" relationship. The FOREIGN KEY goes on the child table, which is the "zero, one,or many" side of the relationship.

---

(The normative practice is to have a foreign key reference the primary key of the target table. To make the `model` column, rather than the `code` column, the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE Act_Model DROP PRIMARY KEY ;
ALTER TABLE Act_Model ADD PRIMARY KEY (model) ;
```

NOTE: There are some significant differences between a UNIQUE KEY and the PRIMARY KEY. For example, there can only be one PRIMARY KEY defined on a table, and the PRIMARY KEY constraint enforces a NOT NULL constraint on the column.)